# Linearised Gravity and Motion of Particles in Background Metric

Tags: general-relativity, linearized-theory

Let's say we have two point particles as our matter source. Suppose we want to solve Einstein Equation Perturbatively and obtain the gravitational wave at the linear order. Let us expand around Minkowski metric and impose the harmonic gauge condition. We get the following equations,

$$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}\tag{1}$$

$$\Box \tilde h_{\mu \nu} \propto T_{\mu \nu}\tag{2} $$
$$\partial^{\mu} \tilde h_{\mu \nu} \tag{3}=0$$

$(2)$ and $(3)$ $\implies \partial^{\mu}T_{\mu \nu}=0$.

This means that the point particles are moving along geodesics of Minkowski space. At the leading order one routinely applies [quadrupole formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_formula) to obtain gravitational waves.

It seems to me that to be consistent one can only apply quadrupole formula for point particles moving along the geodesics of Minkowski space. But I have seen it being frequently applied to obtain GR waves generated by two point particles in circular orbit. Clearly these objects are not moving along geodesics, so how is it consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set it up like this, you will indeed find that the objects move a long geodesics in flat space, and produce no gravitational waves at this order of approximation. The gravitational field will consist of the usual Newtonian potential (at least if you also impose that the particles are not moving at relativistic speeds).

You can alleviate this in two ways, first is to continue in perturbation theory and include the backreaction of the first order gravitational field on the particle trajectories. This will allow them to orbit each other (just as in Newtonian mechanics), and you will find that they generate gravitational waves at some higher order in perturbation theory.

Alternative, you can look at a particle moving an established gravitational background, e.g. the Schwarzschild metric. The particle will now follow a geodesic in this curved background. You can then linearize the Einstein equation around this background and calculate the gravitational waves generated by the particle this way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To handle self gravitating systems, one needs to use other approximation methods. Right?